# En wordpress no mostrar un enlace entre suscriptores

Tags: php, wordpress

solo necesito que en un foro los que son suscriptores no puedan ver un enlace entre si, solo lo puedan ver el dueño del post y los administradores, intente por roles pero cada rol ve su propia conexion perono el de los demas asi que si yo soy el dueño del post no puedo ver el de nadie mas y lo que se quiere es que el dueño del post vea el propio y el de los administradores y no el de los otros suscriptores...

```
echo '<div class="post-message">';
            // Initial escaping.
            $allowed_html = wp_kses_allowed_html('post');
            $allowed_html['iframe'] = array('width' => array(), 'height' => array(), 'src' => array(), 'frameborder' => array(), 'allowfullscreen' => array());
            $post_content = wp_kses($post->text, $allowed_html);
            $post_content = stripslashes($post_content);

            echo '<div id="post-quote-container-'.$post->id.'" style="display: none;"><blockquote><div class="quotetitle">'.__('Quote from', 'asgaros-forum').' '.$this->getUsername($post->author_id).' '.sprintf(__('on %s', 'asgaros-forum'), $this->format_date($post->date)).'</div>'.wpautop($post_content).'</blockquote><br></div>';

            // Automatically embed contents if enabled.
            if ($this->options['embed_content']) {
                global $wp_embed;
                $post_content = $wp_embed->autoembed($post_content);
            }

            // Wrap paragraphs.
            $post_content = wpautop($post_content);

            // Render shortcodes.
            $post_content = $this->shortcode->render_post_shortcodes($post_content);

            // Create nicename-links.
            $post_content = $this->mentioning->nice_name_to_link($post_content);

            // This function has to be called at last to ensure that we dont break links to mentioned users.
            $post_content = make_clickable($post_content);

            // Apply custom filters.
            $post_content = apply_filters('asgarosforum_filter_post_content', $post_content, $post->id);

            echo $post_content;

            **//Esto solo puedan ver el dueño del post que es suscriptor y los administradores del foro pero a su vez el dueño del post vea el de los adminsitradores y no de los otros suscriptores
            echo $this->uploads->show_uploaded_files($post->id, $post->uploads);**

            do_action('asgarosforum_after_post_message', $post->author_id, $post->id);
        echo '</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Bueno para quien lo necesite solo se debe hacer lo siguiente:

```
if ( current_user_can('administrator') || current_user_can('editor')){
            echo $this->uploads->show_uploaded_files($post->id, $post->uploads);
        }elseif ($current_user->ID ==$post->author_id || user_can($post->author_id,'editor') || user_can($post->author_id,'administrator')){
            echo $this->uploads->show_uploaded_files($post->id, $post->uploads);
        }else{
            echo 'ALGUNA COSA AQUI';
        }
```